# How to invoke Lambda function with Event Invocation Type via API Gateway?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Docs says:

> By default, the Invoke API assumes RequestResponse invocation type. You can optionally request asynchronous execution by specifying Event as the InvocationType.

So all I can send to my function (python) is InvocationType:Event everywhere:

```
curl -X POST "https://X.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/Y?InvocationType=Event" 
-d "InvocationType:Event" 
-H "X-Amz-Invocation-Type:Event"

(function sleeps 3 seconds then responses)

null
```

But is not Async... docs also says:

> When you invoke a Lambda function via the AWS console or over HTTPS using Amazon API Gateway, Lambda always uses the RequestResponse invocation type.

I know that can be possible via aws-CLI, what I dont understand if it is possible to do it from API Gateway endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that API Gateway only call lambda functions with RequestResponse by design.

But you can do it writing 2 functions:

1. A "Function Receiver" that invokes the async call to a "Function Executer"

   ```py
   from __future__ import print_function

   import boto3
   import json

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       client = boto3.client('lambda')
       client.invoke_async(
           FunctionName='my_long_task_running_function_executer',
           InvokeArgs=json.dumps(event)
       )
       return {"result": "OK"}
   ```

2. A "Function Executer" that executes the long running task.

Then you will have a process that you can start with an API Gateway and execute it as InvocationType=Event.

Comment: That solution is works, but why using `InvocationType:Event` header not start Lambda in async mode?

Comment: so invoke_async doesn't actually allow you to do anything with the response? that seems useless...

Comment: @AndyHayden the definition of asynchronous is to initiate a process outside of the normal chronological flow and continue processing without waiting for a response. So, no, you cannot do anything with the response. In javascript they get around this by passing a callback to the function. You could do this with AWS Lambda, but it would have to be a callback that the lambda function has access to.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky IME in practice you rarely want to "fire and forget". You can get around this be requesting the url from the API gateway (with an async http request). Although I forget what I was doing in November to want this / whether that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: "rarely want" is very subjective. Every time you have a long running process and you don't want to wait on it, you want to "fire and forget". In that case you are effectively using Lambda as a message queue. For example, transcoding a video. You want to quickly tell the user "transcoding in progress" which the 202 status code of the Event invocation type tells you is true. You don't want to keep the request to lambda open for 30 minutes or so. You'd be better off polling for results or using a callback.

Comment: @mogsdad--Could you also please suggest similar question posted here-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504395/subscriber-and-worker-lambda-python-functions?noredirect=1#comment93881863_53504395
Unable to fetch messages sent from AWS MQ and send to another Lambda function

Answer (score 15):

Create two Lambdas and in the first use [Lambda.Client.invoke](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) with InvocationType=Event in an dedicated ApiGateway request handling Lambda.  The second executes the logic you want the ApiGateway request to asynchronously invoke.

Example dedicated ApiGateway Lambda handler:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='<your_long_task_running_function_executer>',
        InvocationType='Event',
        Payload=json.dumps(event)
    )
    return { "result": "OK" }
```

You would likely want to detect a failure to send the request and other conditions of that sort but as I don't primarily use python, I'll leave that logic up to you.

p.s. note that [invoke_async](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke_async) is deprecated
p.p.s. sorry, my account is new and I don't have the rep to add these as a comment: 0. I borrowed from what you answered; 1. you are using a deprecated api; and 2. you ought (clearly it's been fine) to add `InvocationType = 'Event'` into your call.

Comment: This answer is the correct one and should be accepted

Comment: @jeffrey-- Could you also please suggest similar question posted here-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504395/subscriber-and-worker-lambda-python-functions?noredirect=1#comment93881863_53504395
Unable to fetch messages sent from AWS MQ and send to another Lambda function

Answer (score 2):

According to this article you can pass a header: X-Amz-Invocation-Type: Event
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html

Comment: After a few years, I sure hope people aren't deploying 2 lambdas to get around this problem. I nearly gave up but it's true that you can force API gateway to invoke the lambda asynchronously via the header `X-Amz-Invocation-Type: 'Event'` as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html.

Just be sure to DEPLOY your API changes in the UI (that's what got me).

Answer (score -1):

I know why you want to do this, but it isn't the right solution.

Whatever you do, **don't use two lambda functions.**

You can't control how lambda is being called, async or sync. The caller of the lambda decides that. For APIGW, it decides call lambda sync.

The possible solutions are one of:

- SQS
- Step Functions (SF)
- SNS

In your API, you call out to one of these services, get back a success, and then immediately return a 202 to your caller.

If you have a high volume of single or double action execution use SQS. If you have potentially long running with complex state logic use SF. If you for someone reason want to ignore my suggestions, use SNS.

Each of these can (and should) call back out to a lambda. In the case that you need to run more than 15 minutes, they can call back out to `CodeBuild`. Ignore the name of the service, it's just a lambda that supports up to 8 hour runs.

---

Now, why not use two lambdas (L1, L2)? The answer is simple. Once you respond that your async call was queued (SQS, SF, SNS), to your users (202). They'll expect that it works 100%. But what happens if that L2 lambda fails. It won't retry, it won't continue, and you may never know about it.

That L2 lambda's handler no longer exist, so you don't know the state any more. Further, you could try to add logging to L2 with wrapper `try/catch` but so many other types of failures could happen. Even if you have that, is CloudWatch down, will you get the log? Possible not, it just isn't a reliable strategy. Sure if you are doing something you don't care about, you can build this arch, but this isn't how real production solutions are built. You want a reliable process. You want to trust that the baton was successfully passed to another service which take care of completing the user's transaction. This is why you want to use one of the three services: SQS, SF, SNS.